# Using Ajax to open a Box with HTML Content in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a question regarding basic usage of Ajax/jQuery in Ruby On Rails 3.

I have read many Tutorials, but this Ajax thing is really complicated for me. jQuery isnt used any more and in newer papers were referred to "prototype". And in some other papers you were referred to "Unobtrusive Javascript"... This all is really confusing for me. I didnt find any up-to-date "Ajax Beginner Howto for Ruby on Rails" - so maybe someone could help me here.

What i want to do, for example, is to create a Box with a static HTML Content in (it should display Contact- & Licence Information). I found this Question [Ajax pop up box using Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309431/ajax-pop-up-box-using-ruby-on-rails) which is exactly what i search (facebox seems to be perfect), but if i try to do it like:

`<a href="remote.html" rel="facebox">text</a>` (in my index.html.erb view)

(see http://defunkt.io/facebox/) and load the dependencies:

`<link href="/facebox/facebox.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`

`<script src="/facebox/facebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` (in my application.html.erb view)

without loading jquery and with jquery from google. Default RubyOnRails Javascript is loaded additionally.

... it doesnt work. Sadly.

I there someone how could bring light into the Ajax Rails thing for me? Maybe white some little examples?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript

Comment: What do you mean by "default RoR JavaScript"? jQuery is the default JS library now. And AFAIK you need to actually attach a handler to the link and tell facebox what to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "jquery isn't used anymore"? It just became the new default in Rails 3.1;

Comment: Ah, okay. Sorry for the confusion. I thought jQuery was replaced by another AJAX Framework :-(. Same thing by watching Railscasts Episode 205. I didnt remember where i have red it, but ".js.erb" as an extension is depricated in Rails 3 :-/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started, I suggest you to look into the following resources:

- [railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript)
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/

The first one is a railscasts-episode by Ryan Bates, which is a really great start.
The second one is an absolute beginners tutorial, which is admittedly not comletely flawless, but it should give you a headstart into the right direction.

To get a deeper insight you should check the following articles:

- http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/
- http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/
- http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms-data-type-with-jquery/

All those resources are available on the web for free. One last (very highly) recommendation though is the updated book "[Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails)" (partly) written by David Heinemeier Hansson himself.

It shows you how to use Ajax with jQuery within a working (little bit bigger) rails-application in a very straightforward and easy-to-follow manner.

Hope this helps
cheers

Comment: Agile Web Development uses prototype instead of JQuery fyi

Comment: @Mike: check the [updated version](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) ;-)