# opening a jquery popup form in rails to display comments and create a comment

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm have the standard comments controller attached to my project through a has_many association.

I have a set of rows that show the latest comments.

When the user clicks on the comment that is displayed (let's say they click on title), then i want

1)a popup to open that shows
 a) a comment submit form 
b) underneath the comment form, a list of all comments associated with the project.

i'm having a hard time with getting the popup to work and then populating the popup with 1 and 2 from above.

when i submit hte form, i want it to refresh the popup with the same setup (new comment form and list of existing comments below.

i think i can do this with jquery and rails, but not sure how. i'm using jquery-rails.

thanks for the help!

Comment: Your question is too broad. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What does your popup code look like now?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're going to want to use a little AJAX in your Rails.  Rails' unobtrusive JavaScript and AJAX capability allows you to load remote views into pop-ups without reloading the page, and I think what you probably want to do here is load a remote view containing your comment edit/display combination layout into your pop-up.  Then have AJAX update the main page once the dialog is closed.

I would start with this short tutorial on [using unobtrusive JavaScript with AJAX with Rails 3](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/), then check out [Facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox), which I learned about from [this post that asks a question related to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309431/ajax-pop-up-box-using-ruby-on-rails).

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

As a start you could take at look at the [JQuery dialog demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog) - put a form inside the dialog and submit it with ajax (remote => true) and close the dialog if successful. Evan's answer will give you a prettier and ultimately better solution (as will many other lightbox-like gems) but using a jquery dialog is probably the simplest way to start

Answer (score 0):

I went with Facebox and both answers were good so thank you. **However i have the following problem:** Any ideas?

with Facebox, i'm getting raw text when i use it for the `('#facebox .content')` selector. It works fine for `('#facebox')` or `('#facebox .popup')`.  Have you guys run into this? By raw output, i mean the following:

```
$('#facebox .content').html("
\n Hello from box div\n<\/div> ");
```

that's what shows up in the box. and only for the .content selector!

in application.js i have:

```
$('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox(function($) {
   $.getScript(this.href);
});
```

in my controller:

```
 respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @project }  
    format.js {render :layout => false} 
  end
```

in my show.js.erb:

```
$('#facebox .content').html("<%= escape_javascript(render("spaces"))%>");
```

Comment: just revisiting this question. I ended up using colorbox on a recent project and i'm pretty happy with it. Actually more so than facebox as i found it easier to use.  So that may be another option for someone looking to integrate this.

Comment: Best not to post a question as an answer to another question